# how to detect whether file download successfully from client side in mean/angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have created a chat application in which I have kept file sending functionality over chat windows. Now I want to remove files from the server end when clients successfully download them.
I'm using the MEAN stack.

```
router.post("/postChatFileSend",ensureAuthenticatedForPost,function(req,res) {

    if (req.body.fileName)
    {
        var filePath = __dirname + '/../public/ChatFile/'+req.body.fileName;
        fs.unlink(filePath, function (err) {
        })
    };

    return res.json({"status": true,"messages":"messages read sucessfully"});  
})

router.get('/downloadChatFile/:fileName',ensureAuthenticatedForPost, function(req, res) {

    var file = __dirname + '/../public/ChatFile/'+req.params.fileName;
    res.download(file); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery File Download](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) plugin for your purpose, it's a simple example you can use in your client for manage the downloaded file:

```
$.fileDownload('urlForYourFile')
    .done(function () { 
        alert('File download a success!'); 
        $.post('/postChatFileSend', {fileName: 'fileName'}, function(data) {
            //Check the response, if the status propery is true, the file must have been removed from the server 
        });
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('An error has ocurred');
    });
```

Here there are [more examples](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)

Comment: @TushBedva if the answer was helpfull please vote up, not at all bro ;)