# Detect file download with internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, web, events

I am looking for a way to detect when user download a file event in internet explorer, but I didn't found a way yet, is it possible at all? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to detect file download in browser using [jQuery File Download plugin](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload). For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782417/how-to-detect-whether-file-download-successfully-from-client-side-in-mean-angula).

> Note - You must also write a cookie in conjunction with using this plugin in the server's response headers

But I think you can't achieve your goal with only client-side code due to security issues. From the browser side, we can't reach the file save dialog from browser as it's OS level. From the file side, you don't have access to the files in the server and you don't know the states of the files. You could also refer to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334881/detect-when-user-accepts-to-download-a-file) in this thread for more information.

Comment: I will accept, though I need it from client side only